# Как реализовать выезжающую панель в android?

Tags: java, android

Как реализовать выезжающую панель снизу в android (поверх основного окна)?

Аналогично панели в приложении Periscope с трансляциями, когда нажимаешь на метку трансляции.
[image: Periscope]

Comment: Многие о таком приложении даже не слышали. Будет лучше, если вы гифку приложите.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего вам надо действовать так:

1. Основная разметка - `Relative/FrameLayout`
2. По событию (например нажатию на кнопку) создаёте/инфлейтите разметку нужную в переменную.
3. Если нужна анимация - запускаете её. В ней нужную вьюху перемещаете из-за границы экрана наверх. Если анимация не нужна - сразу к п.4. переходите.
4. И в слушателе её окончания добавляете разметку из п.2. в разметку из п.1.

Comment: Я сделал упрощенную версию того, что вы предложили. Но как сделать, чтобы эта View была поверх основной разметки, а не смещала ее вверх?

Comment: Проблема решена! Необходимо использовать для этого FrameLayout. Спасибо.